# How do I change the background color of a cocoa NSBrowser?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I change the background color of a cocoa NSBrowser from the default white? Do I need to override something else to do this? I've searched online and not found anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've not used NSBrowser very often, but [the Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBrowser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBrowser/setBackgroundColor) clearly shows a setBackgroundColor method. Does this not do what you want?